# Why won't a simple image load in Phaser in the browser?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Right now, I am following this tutorial: https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/index

I followed the first bit and got the part to render a sky.png into the browser, but my browser always ends up blank. I even just tried to open their completed examples, but get blank. Do I need to run it as a server or something?
I tried npm install, that didn't work either.

I followed this tutorial: https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/index

The zip file it references under 'Requirements' won't load the part1.html, part.html, etc pages.

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Making your first Phaser 3 Game - Part 3</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update
        }
    };

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload ()
    {
        this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
        this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
        this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
        this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/bomb.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'assets/dude.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
    }

    function create ()
    {
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
    }

    function update ()
    {
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have an image in the path `assets/sky.png` relative to your HTML file?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk yes, it came with the package I downloaded. I even just put sky.png in the same folder as the .html file and renamed it to 'sky.png' and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to empty your cache and executed a hard reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to open the html files directly in your browser? If so, that is why this doesn't work. Please see the [Phaser Getting Started Guide](http://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started-phaser3) for details on how to configure a local web server to serve the files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need a server hosting your javascript and html in order for this to work. If you simply drag html files into your browser from your local directory, the session will not be able to access the other needed files because they're still only saved locally to your computer. The Phaser Getting Started Guide goes more in-depth, but essentially you wouldn't want a web page to be able to access your computer's local files.

Did any of the above solutions work for you? For me, I've used a Simple HTTP Server with Python. I was referencing my images correctly and had my web server hosted correctly. When using developer tools, there were no error messages.. I was banging my head against the wall for hours. The Phaser API was not able to tell what the local directory (http://192.168.0.2:8080/) was from the webpage from some reason.

I fixed my issue by using the following path for my images:

```
'http://192.168.0.2:8080/assets/sky.png'
```

where 192.168.0.2 was my local IP address hosting the server
&
8080 was the port I was using for communications

Alternative to adding that lengthy file path for each of your images, you can call the `this.load.setBaseURL('http://192.168.0.2:8080')` function in combination with what you already have.

For example, see the following code:

```
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 200 }
        }
    },
    scene: {
        
        preload: preload,
        create: create
    }
};
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload ()
{
    console.log('preload');
    this.load.setBaseURL('http://192.168.0.2:8080');
    this.load.image('bombP','bowmb.png');
    this.load.image('einMary','/bowmb.png');
}

function create ()
{
    console.log('create');
    this.add.image(126, 119, 'bombP');
    this.add.image(222,269,'einMary');
    //var s = game.add.sprite(80,0,'einMary');
    //s.rotation=0.219;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed Cryptox Rain's answer except I used http-server from npm and needed to enable CORS

added this at the beginning of my preload function

```
function preload ()
{
    this.load.setBaseURL('http://localhost:3000');
    ...

}
```

then install and run the server from the terminal

```
# install
npm install http-server -g 

# run server
http-server -a localhost -p 3000 --cors
```